# conditional statement not responding in js (node)

Tags: javascript, string, node.js, conditional-statements

ive been up late working on a bit of code, and i made a edit somewhere and now it will not respond. take this piece of code for example:

```
function message_call(message, socket) {
    if (message.length > 1) {
        var func = message[0];
        var string = message.slice(1);
        var string = string.join(' ')
    } else {
        var func = message[0];
        var string = '';
    };
    if (func[0] == '$') {
        if (methods.hasOwnProperty(func)) {
            if (string.length > 0) {
                methods[func](string, socket)
            } else {
                console.log(string.length)
            };
        };
    };
};
```

if the string.length is greater than 0, it is supposed to call a value from the methods with string and socket. if it is 0, "else" it is supposed to call the command with only socket. for example. if the message were to equal "$say hi" then the func would be "$say" while the string would be "hi". and the value for "$say" would be called from the methods. however if the message were to equal "$say" then the function would be that and the string would be "". i took out the call to method on the else and put console.log to see if it was even responding. however it wont even log the string.length if the length is 0. out side of the function it will, the question is, why will it not print to the console on the else? why is the conditional statement not working right. it should do one thing if greater than 0 and another else. however it only does it on >0 and is unresponsive on the else.

Comment: Hitting the space bar now and then costs nothing.

Comment: from printing out the string.length outside of the if statement i have confirmed that it is in fact 0 when there is only the function. i have even tried if (string.length == 0){console.log(string.length)}; and was unsuccessful. it just wont respond

Comment: or "array" as the message is split on (' ') from a previous function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try defining func/string at the beginning of the method maybe, rather than in the if/else blocks.

```
var func = null, string = null;
// remainder of code. drop using 'var' when assigned values
```

it's possible that string is null or doesn't have a length property in the context where you think it's failing.

also, make sure you're using semicolons consistently.

Comment: i have tried it even by pre defining the string. however it will only do one of the conditions. it will never do the condition on the variable generated in the else in the first condition.

Comment: if string was 0 then func had trailing white space which prevented the function from working. but thanks for answering the question.

Answer (score 1):

this is not really an answer, but i have isolated the problem. when the string = '', meaning there is only the func, for some reason it goes to a new line, or adding on white space making it so the command wont go through. any suggestions?

Edit: using func.strip() did the job. 4 hours of debugging and having to print out every single piece of data to solve it.